# Passing String value from one page to another page in React-Native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I am trying to capture user input value and set it into a state and pass the new state (updated value) to second page to be used in a function.

The overall app is to create a name for a group chat and pass the NAME of group to the next page to be used as one of the parameters in the `createGroup()` function.

The concept code would be having `this.state.channelName` and when user input new value into `TextInput` i will capture the string value and `_onChangeText(newName){this.setState({channelName: newName})}`.

After that i will have a button to `push` to a new page and use the `newName` in the function.

The result should be having the groupName that contains all the selected users.

Hope i made myself clear thank you

Comment: So, where do you need help? you seems to have answered your own question.

Comment: i dont know where and how to pass the newName to second page. I tried to use export {channelName} but its not working

Comment: which means now i only able to perform state change within first page only. and not passed to the page i wanted it to be in

Comment: how do you go to the second page ? Using [react navigation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/) ?

Comment: yes. example would be this.props.navigator.push({name: 'inviteUser', channel: this.state.channel});

Comment: Hi sorry i think i made a mistake here. its actually "import NavigationExperimental from 'react-native-deprecated-custom-components';"
this is actually a sample app i get from open source and i am trying to modify it into a customized one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pass data during navigation using react-navigation

```
this.props.navigation.navigate(component, { param1: value1, param2: value2, ...})
```

If you want to update the state for another component, you must maintain the state in redux / flux and update the state in this component and map the state to a prop in next component.